# Why can't I get married in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

Every time I try to get married in the game everybody gets set up for the ceremony, people get in place and then everybody just looks at each other,I can't move, And I can't say anything all I can do is pause and load save files. Has this happened to anybody before and how can I get married. I am a gay Khajiit who is marrying a male Argonian, named Derkeethus, is that helps.

Comment: Do you have any mods installed? Regardless of if you think they would interfere.